# How can I switch the TV to the Pi's HDMI input on a key press/mouse click?

Tags: hdmi, cec-client

I've got a TV with an Apple TV, Pi, and a PS4 plugged into it. Both the Apple TV and the PS4 switch to their HDMI inputs when I click the remote or turn the controller on. How can I achieve the same thing with the PI and its keyboard and/or mouse?

Both `tvservice` and `vcgencmd` don't seem to have anything helpful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90000/hdmi-cec-switch-the-device-to-the-port-where-raspberry-is-connected) from five months ago and the proposed solution is to run the following:

```
echo "as" | cec-client RPI -s -d
```

Here's a relatively recent tutorial on [how to use the `cec-client`](https://blog.gordonturner.com/2016/12/14/using-cec-client-on-a-raspberry-pi/).